# python weird result of string append string

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x

I am using flask socketio (python 3.7) to receive data from web side (js)

Script:

```
@socketio.on("pfile-input", namespace="/pfile")
def pimage_input(data):
    global pty_path

    print(type(data))
    print(data)

    print(type(pty_path))
    print(pty_path)

    file_to_read = pty_path + "/" + data
    print(type(file_to_read))
    print(file_to_read)
```

The output is :

```
<class 'str'>
banner.png
<class 'str'>
/Users/supersuraccoon/Desktop/xxx/server/flask/templates
<class 'str'>
/banner.pngrsuraccoon/Desktop/xxx/server/flask/templates
```

As you can see the result is not what I am excepting which should be :

```
 /Users/xxx/Desktop/xxx/server/flask/templates/banner.png
```

I really can not figure out where goes wrong.

Any advice will be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Give os.path.join a try as suggested below. See if that helps. Also, if you are just using global variable, you don’t need “global pty_path” which is only used when you want to change a global variable.

Comment: Try printing out `repr(data)` and check for any special characters. This could be the result of an extra carriage return character involved.

Comment: I tried `print(repr(pty_path))` and the out put is `'banner.png'` and found a trailing `\r` and now everything works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the `os.path.join` function to concatenate the paths in a more built-in manner.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried `file_to_read = os.path.join(pty_path, data)` and removed `global pty_path` and result is still the same `/banner.pngrsuraccoon/Desktop/xxx/server/flask/templates`

Comment: It seems like the string `/banner.png` replaced the first part of pty_path instead of append at the end of pty_path